# WWW::Scripter issues with window.history

Tags: javascript, perl, mechanize

I am using **perl** modules `WWW::Scripter` (based on `WWW::Mechanize`) with **JavaScript** plugin and I have problems with an essential JavaScript statement.

```
use WWW::Scripter;
...
my $web = WWW::Scripter->new(agent => '...', autocheck => 1);
...
$web->use_plugin('JavaScript');
...
$web->add_header(Referer => 'http://...');
...
$web->get($url);
```

where source code includes essential JavaScript statement, such as:

```
var x = window.history.length;
```

and this statement cannot be executed with `WWW::Scripter` module.

I have no issues with any other, even very complicated jquery statements. Just this one!

Any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have been in contact with the author of `WWW::Scripter` module and the above issue had been accepted as a bug. New `WWW::Scripter` **version 0.026** with fix has been just uploaded. It should work now...

[UPDATE]

New **version 0.027** has been just released. After fix of `window.history` object in version 0.026, the latest one contains fix for `javaEnabled` (as implementation of this one was missing) and `referer` fix for all sub-requests.